# My site redirect me to my ip address

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, moodle

Hi i'm using nginx and ubuntu 18
for my moodle site

i add a domain, and everytime i try to access it , it alway redirect me to my IP address.

here is my block

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/html/moodle;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name  moodle.mysqite.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /dataroot/ {
    internal;
    alias /var/www/html/moodledata/;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Check your moodle configuration. Most probably the base URL is configured with the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

actually moodle did the redirect.
I have to change config.php inside moodle folder for the site